Get Balance from Liquidity Account
before I start: Im kinda a newbie in programming so theres big chances I just miss something here.
So, I want to get the balance of the Wsol of an liquidity Account on Raydium. I got this Account from a Jupiter Quote where I found the AMM? address. Below you see the Account on solscan. So far I only managed to get the Sol balance (0.006124) which is not what I wanted.
I don't want to rely on Raydium API or any other. Just on RPC-requests or the Jupiter API since im already using it to get quotes.
I already tried most of the functions. getTokenAccountsByDelegate Doesnt seem to work but the other methodes I tried from the Solanas Doc. didn't give me any good results aswell. How can I find the WSOL balance? Am I even looking in the right place?

